# How to prevent a click() event through a child div to a parent div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events, click

Situation:

```
<div class="header">
    <div style="float: left;" class="headerTitle">+ OPEN</div>
    <div class="closeBtn" style="float: right;">- CLOSE</div>
 </div> 
<div class="touristenContent">.....</div>
```

Visually:

```
|+Open..............................|-Close|..| (header)

|............Content..........................|
```

Header DIV is a 'big button' with jQuery click() event for opening the content.
The close DIV is inside the big header DIV and represents the **close button** also with click() event to close the content.
This **close button** is only visible by clicking on the big header.

Clickng on the header and oppening the content works as expecting but clicking on the **close button** let the click event through to the header DIV. The content closes and opens again beacause of two click events.

So how can i design the whole thing properly to make the **close button** solid and to prevent click through it to the header?

Comment: Not *every* JavaScript question on Stack Overflow needs to be demonstrated on jsfiddle.net.  While it *does* help for many questions, I'm beginning to get the feeling that some users are considering it mandatory.  Not sure who down voted, but this is a perfectly valid question without a jsfiddle to back it up.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to [stop the event from propagating](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) up the DOM tree:

```
$('.closeBtn').click(function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();

    // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$('.closeBtn').click(function (event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   //   ... your code here
   return false;
});
```

that should do the trick, so everytime you click on close it will not affect your header div,

Comment: Thank You very much! Is it important to have 'return false;' at the end?

Comment: @PaulGeisler: `return false;` would also cancel the browser's default action.  In this case, there is no default action for clicking a `<div>` element so it isn't necessary.

Comment: If you want to cancel the default action, event.preventDefault() is the right way, at least in 2016.

Comment: The solution didn't work for me without the `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

Why not hook open event with `<div style="float: left;" class="headerTitle">+ OPEN</div>` instead of parent div. Otherwise `return false` or `stopPropagation` from inner div click handler