# No onclick when child is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="outerElement">
    <div class="text">
     Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet
    </div>
    <div class="attachment">
      <!-- Image from youtube video here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have a jQuery onclick event on the `.outerElement` however, I don't want the `.outerElement` onclick event to be called when I click on the attachment, is there some way to prevent this or to check which element is clicked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent a click() event through an internal div to parent div in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835775/how-to-prevent-a-click-event-through-an-internal-div-to-parent-div-in-jquery) and [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli) and [How can I stop an onclick event from firing for parent element when child is clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/985389/218196).

Comment: Sorry, I did a few searches in both google and stackoverflow but couldnt find any results that could help me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` on the child element.

```
$(".attachment").on("click", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log( "I was clicked, but my parent will not be." );
});
```

This prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM to the parent node.

Also part of the `event` object is the [`target` member](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/). This will tell you which element triggered the event to begin with.  However, in this instance, `stopPropagation` appears to be the best solution.

```
$(".outerElement").on("click", function(event){
  console.log( event.target );
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what the performance implications of allowing the propagation from the child elements, but I solved this by comparing event.target and event.currentTarget:

```
onClick={(event) => {
  if (event.target === event.currentTarget) {
     console.log('Handle click');
  }
}}
```

This is React ^
More generalized javascript code would be:

```
$('.outerElement').click(function(event) {
  if (event.currentTarget !== event.target) {
    return;
  }
  // Handle event
});
```

---

You can also filter out specific element types like so:

```
$('.outerElement').click(function(event) {
  if (['input', 'select', 'option'].indexOf(event.target.localName) >= 0) {
    return;
  }
  // Handle event
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This works without jQuery

```
<div class="outerElement">
    <div class="attachment">Hello</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByClassName('outerElement').onclick = function(){

    alert('You clicked on parent');

}
document.getElementsByClassName('attachment').onclick = function(){

    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('You clicked on child');

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply setting `onclick="event.stopPropagation();"` on the children will do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can prevent the event from firing when the `attachment` item is clicked but you can certainly filter for it

```
$('.outerElement').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('attachment')) {
    return;
  }
  // Handle event
});
```