# click event replication

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this structure

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li....
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

and in Jquery

```
$(div).click(function(){...});
$(li).click(function(){....});
```

Now my problem is when I click on li, div click event also firing. how can set to only fire li click event when click on li.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent execution of parent event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398582/prevent-execution-of-parent-event-handler) and [How to prevent a click() event through an internal div to parent div in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835775/how-to-prevent-a-click-event-through-an-internal-div-to-parent-div-in-jquery) and [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

```
$(li).click(function(e) {e.stopPropagation()...})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(div).click(function(){...});
$(li).click(function(ev){ ev.stopPropagation(); /* other code here */ });
```

Use [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: whats the difference b/w preventdefault and stopPropagation

Comment: @rajuk see http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ with `preventDefault` the event still bubbles up the DOM tree

Comment: ...see http://jsfiddle.net/wxXc8/

Answer (score 2):

Return false from the `li`s event, this will stop it bubbling up the DOM tree.

Update, and for good measure do `event.preventDefault()` too, `event` being the first argument passed into the handling function.

Comment: what's the default action to prevent while clicking a `<li>` element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) like

```
$(li).click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation() });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
$(li).click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    //you code here
})
```